# MS-Access or Excel: Convert data from rows to columns, in unknown range of columns

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a table like this:

```
 **customer_id        product_id**        
  1                  1234        
  1                  1125        
  1                  6528    
  2                  5645       
  2                  5528       
  3                  4565
```

And I want to make a query that will give the same information, where each consumer will have one row, and each product_id will be in a separate column, when I do not know how many columns are needed, because each consumer has made a different amount of purchases,
This is the result I want:

```
**customer_id        First_product              Second_product              Third_product      **
  1                  1234                         1125                         6528
  2                  5645                         5528 
  3                  4565
```

Note this:
[How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv?rq=1)

There he does a similar thing, but all the values are in the same column with a comma between them, I want each value to have a separate column.

Comment: I provided an answer in another question you deleted. I tested the query and it worked for me. Same answer can be applied here only instead of Balance as data you have product_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, you can do this using `Power Query` (*available in Excel 2010+*)

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"customer_id"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [customer_id=nullable number, product_id=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Product", each Table.Column([Grouped],"product_id")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Product", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(
            #"Extracted Values", "Product", 
            Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Grouped"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
TRANSFORM First(Table1.product_id) AS ProdID
SELECT Table1.customer_id
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.customer_id
PIVOT DCount("*","Table1","customer_id=" & [customer_id] & " AND [product_id]<" & product_id)+1;
```

If there is a unique record identifier field (autonumber should serve):

```
TRANSFORM First(Table1.product_id) AS ProdID
SELECT Table1.customer_id
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.customer_id
PIVOT DCount("*","Table1","customer_id=" & [customer_id] & " AND [id]<" & id)+1;
```

Or use order date field instead of ID field in DCount() expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check it out again in Access