SQL show child information in columns instead of rows
I have two tables, one with addresses and the other with people. There is no releation between this tables.
What I need is, based on address (street + number) to show me all people (names) living at that address.
I have;
SELECT people.*, address.*
FROM people
LEFT JOIN people ON people.street = address.street AND people.number = address.number

This give me the results back in rows; every people living at address x returns a row.
address a | person 1
address a | person 2
address a | person 3
address b | person 4
address b | person 5
address c | person 6

But I need it in colums, as in every person that lives on an address value in a different column, like;
address a | person1 | person 2 | person 3
address b | person4 | person5
address c | person6

I think I've done it before, but I can't seem te find out anymore who it worked... Any help please?

A SQL query results in a table that you define in the query so to say. This means that you must know which columns to show when writing the query. This can not be a variable number of columns. If you want to show your persons in columns, then you must decide how many columns you provide for this, e.g. 4 columns for a maximum number of four persons to show for an address. (That fourth column would be null for all rows in your example.) Such tasks are better done in your app instead of in SQL. In your app you can loop through the rows and create as many columns in your grid as becomes necessary.

What DBMS are you using? Some features are only available in particular DBMS or the syntax may differ from one DBMS to another. Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS.

Using Access as DB, all the data comes from Excel / CSV. Any way perhaps to achive this in Excel.

The max. number of people living at 1 single address is 6 btw

Is it acceptable to have one column with multiple names like person1, person2, person3 ? As Thorsten says, your SELECT ... already determines how many columns there are in the result set.

In SQL-Server you would pivot on Row_Number but in Access I am not sure that feature exists.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027634/rown-number-over-partition-in-access-pivot-with-two-row-of-data-to-fetch

multiple names in 1 column might also be acceptable for now :)

Either use VBA to concatenate names into a single string for each address or pivot with CROSSTAB - review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400911/pivot-query-in-ms-access
